# Summernote remove resize bar

Tags: javascript, css, summernote

I'm using summernote 0.8.2 and I'm trying to remove the resize bar at the bottom of the text editor like the one shown [here](http://summernote.org/getting-started/#height-and-focus). I tried options such as the ones listed below. Does anyone know what is the correct way to do this?

```
$("#summernote").summernote({
    toolbar: [
        ['para', ['ul']]
    ],
    focus: true,
    disableResize: true,            // Does not work
    disableResizeEditor: true,      // Does not work either
    resize: false                   // Does not work either
});
$('.note-statusbar').hide()             // Does not work either
```

Comment: Try with `disableResizeEditor: true` | Also found this:https://github.com/summernote/summernote/issues/1931

Comment: I tried those as well and it did not work.

Comment: `disableResizeEditor: true` and `$('.note-statusbar').hide() ` both worked fine for me. The first makes the statusbar unable to resize and the second hides it.

Comment: Ok, you can just hide it with CSS: `.note-statusbar{display:none;}` did the job.

Comment: When I used both at the same time, it worked like you said. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It worked when I did the following. Credit to [yuri636](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3499595/yuriy636)

```
$("#summernote").summernote({
    toolbar: [
        ['para', ['ul']]
    ],
    focus: true,
    disableResizeEditor: true
});
$('.note-statusbar').hide();
```

Answer (score 2):

I have found a way to resize the summernote text area, use the class .note-editabe, example  :

```
$(".note-editable").height(100) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

for removing dragging resize u can give the property to summernote

```
disableResizeImage: true
```

to remove percentage of size menu you can add a css

```
.note-resize{
    display: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$('.summernote').summernote({

    disableResizeEditor: true
});

$('.note-statusbar').hide();
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!